# svg tooltips aren't showing when pointer-events: none; is used

Tags: html, css, svg, tooltip, pointer-events

How do I fix this so that the tool tip is able to be seen?

If I remove pointer-effects, then the video is not able to be clicked.

How the code works is, you click on the play image and a video appears.

Removing pointer effects will cause the video not to be able to be clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/zk4vmf8L/

```
.background svg{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
        <div class="background">
            <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 856.3 856.2">
                <title>Random Music</title>
```

Comment: your question has no video

Comment: code needs to be in the question, not just in some offsite link.